# how to create usdt wallet via api and receive transactions

Tags: node.js, cryptocurrency

I'm new to this area and don't understand anything yet. I need to create a USDT wallet and accept it into payments, but I need to confirm the payment based on recent transactions.
I can't find anything that can solve my problem in Google.

On the server side, I usually use node js, maybe there are some packages?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are two most popular **.js** libraries for the matter you want to achieve - **web3.js** and **Ethers.js**.

I would recommend you to dig into one of those.

Shortly:

1. Connect to the Ethereum network https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3.html#web3-object
2. Create a contract entity (USDT) in order to interact with the wanted contract
   https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html
3. For wallet creation
   https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=wallet#wallet-create
4. In order to confirm the payments in erc-20 you would like to subscribe to the blockchain events (this will help you to catch wanted transactions):
   https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#

Comment: Can you advice an API to create TCR20 protocol usdt addresses and make transactions with them